# Error in reading txt files using Path::Tiny in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to use the [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module to read some text files.

I created the list of file names I wanted to read in file `list.txt`, but when I run my code I get this error message

> ```
> Error open <<:raw:encoding<UTF-8>> on '[thefirstfilenames.txt]': Invalid argument at Test2.PL line 15.
> ```

My code is as follows:

```
use strict;
use 5.010;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny qw(path); # http://perlmaven.com/use-path-tiny-to-read-and-write-file

my $file = "list.txt";
open (FH, "< $file") or die "Can't open $file for read: $!";
my @list = <FH>;
close FH or die "Cannot close $file: $!"; 

my $size = @list;

for ( my $i = 0; $i < $size; $i++ ) {
    my $filename = "$list[$i]";
    my $content = path($filename)->slurp_utf8;
    print "$content\n";
}
```

Is there any solution to this? It works fine when I put the name of the file one by one manually.

Comment: You probably need to `chomp` your file name. And you can ditch the "C style" for loop in favor of `for my $filename (@list)`.

Comment: As long as you're using Path::Tiny, you might as well use [Path::Tiny->lines](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#lines-lines_raw-lines_utf8) to read in the list.

Comment: Could you please post the contents of file list.txt?

Comment: @squiguy You are right. The use of `chomp` solves my problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got `Invalid argument` ([EINVAL](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)) as an error, but it's clear from the error message the lines in the file contain things like `[thefirstfilenames.txt]` with the brackets. That's probably not a valid filename, you'll need to remove them either from the file or in the program.

Buuut... I suspect you didn't show us the real error message, really important when asking for debugging help. I suspect what you got instead is something like this, newline and all.

```
Error open <<:raw:encoding<UTF-8>> on 'somefilename.txt
': Invalid argument at Test2.PL line 15.
```

When you read from a file, each line still has a newline on it. You need to remove it. This is generally done with [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) and can be done on a whole list at once.

---

There's other things that can be done to improve the code. Since you're already using Path::Tiny, replace the start of the program with a call to [`Path::Tiny->lines`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#lines-lines_raw-lines_utf8). And call it what's in it: `@filenames`.

```
my @filenames = path($file)->lines_utf8;
chomp @filenames;
```

Most importantly to get rid of the C-style for loop and [let Perl iterate through the `@filenames`](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/foreach.html).

```
for my $filename (@filenames) {
    my $content = path($filename)->slurp_utf8;
    say $content;
}
```

Comment: When I ran it, I got the same error format - with brackets and newline.  Killer answer - spot on.  The only thing I would have added is a test of $path->exists prior to the attempted reading.

Comment: @Marty No need, Path::Tiny will throw an exception if the file does not exist. And checking if it does exist doesn't mean it can be opened for reading, you'd need to check `-r`, but again it's redundant with Path::Tiny. It's also non-atomic; just because it existed/was readable when you looked doesn't mean it will still be so when you try to open it. The best way to check if a file can be opened for reading is to open it for reading.

Comment: It's important to note that `slurp_utf8` also opens the file with a `:raw` layer. In my opinion this is inappropriate in the light of Perl's text IO conventions, and will cause data read from a file originating on Windows to retain the CR characters that Perl normally removes on input and restores on output

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for your detailed explanations. Yes, you are absolutely right. I got the exact same message what you think. Just tried to change the file name. Now I understand that is not a good idea when I ask debugging. So the use of `chomp` solves my problem basically. For the part of removing C-style for loop, in fact I got this message: `Can't use string <"Path::Tiny"> as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at c:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/Path/Tiny.pm line 1024.` I am wondering if I did something wrong in my program applying your suggestion.

Comment: @Schwern I am pretty new in this, so I apologize if I am asking too simple question again. But I don't understand what this ARRAY ref in the message. I appreciate all your help. My code is as follows: `use strict;
use 5.010;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny qw(path); # http://perlmaven.com/use-path-tiny-to-read-and-write-file

Path::Tiny->lines;

my $file = "list.txt";
my @filenames = path($file)->lines_utf8;
chomp @filenames;

for my $filename (@filenames) {
 my $content = path($filename)->slurp_utf8;
 say $content;
}`

Comment: @ykjang322 `Path::Tiny->lines` didn't mean to literally use that code. It meant to use the `lines` method of `Path::Tiny` on a `Path::Tiny` object as illustrated in the following line: `path($file)->lines_utf8;`.

Comment: @Schwern I get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you don't remove the unwanted characters from the ends of the file names read from `list.txt`. That means every values of `$filename` will still be contained in square brackets `[ ... ]` and have an unwanted `"\n"` appended to it that you should remove

Here's a rewrite of your own code that fixes this. It also corrects some old-fashioned technniques, such as using *lexical file handles* with the *three-parameter form of `open`*, and iterating over the *contents* of `@list` instead of its indexes

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny 'path';

my $file = 'list.txt';

my @files = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};
    map { / \[ ( [^\[\]]+ ) \] /x } <$fh>;
};

for my $file ( @files) {
    my $content = path($file)->slurp_utf8;
    print $content, "\n";
}
```

This will work for you, but in my opinion `Path::Tiny` is unnecessary here, and `slurp_utf8` retains the CR character in Windows line endings which is not standard Perl behaviour and probably not what is wanted. A slurp is simple to do using a `do` block that opens the file and localizes `$/`. It has the advantage that everything is done in standard Perl, and anyone reading it doesn't have to guess at what `path($file)->slurp_utf8` might do (which clearly isn't a straightforward slurp as you might expect). Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'list.txt';

my @files = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};
    <$fh>;
};
chomp @files;

for my $file ( @files) {

    my $content = do {
        open my $fh, '<:encoding(utf-8)', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};
        local $/;
        <$fh>;
    };

    print $content, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Path::Tiny is *not* the problem. How did you conclude it's introducing extra newlines? Going back to weird Perl I/O idioms is regressing.

Comment: @Schwern: I said nowhere that the module was the problem. Now please keep your fury more contained and your `Path::Tiny` fan mail just between you and the author

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for your help. I think I need to study perl a bit more to understand your answer. The second program you showed works perfect for me, but the first program does not. I assume that is because I did not use the square bracket for the file name in fact. Thank you!